# What is the solution to the following integral? Dirac Delta function must be invoked at some point.

Tags: definite-integrals, dirac-delta, electromagnetism

Evaluate the following integral,where is the usefulness of the delta function in the evaluation?

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(r)\nabla\frac{\vec{r}-i}{(r-i)^3} dr$$

Comment: What is $f(x)$ and $i$ ?

Comment: @A---B I is the imaginary number really and f(r) is an arbitrary function in r

Comment: Is $r$ a vector ?

Comment: Use the fact that $$-\nabla \cdot \frac{\bf{r}-\bf{r_{0}}}{\lvert\,\bf{r}-\bf{r_{0}}\,\rvert^{3}}=-4\pi\delta(\bf{r}-\bf{r_{0}})$$

Comment: Then you may need a Laplace Transform

Comment: @BenjaminMoss I think Jason has mistaken. I think he mean to write the expression you wrote.

Comment: Yes r is a vector and are you suggesting we treat the i as the vector r nought? How exactly?

Comment: How exactly do you propose subtracting the imaginary unit from a vector quantity? Are you sure it isnt the unit vector $\hat{i}$?

Comment: @JasonMars Where did you get this problem from ?

Comment: I beg your pardon, we treat I as vector then surely we can use the identity Benjamin Moss suggested, yes?

Comment: No you can't use it, we you are allowed to **prove it**  @BenjaminMoss How do you prove it, Fourier transform ?

Comment: @JasonMars No you can't the identity Benjamin suggested has divergence but your integral has gradient, that is why I asked you where you get this problem from, it does not seem correct.

Comment: I'm tempted to put a bounty on this mysterious problem...

Comment: The first time I see an imaginary number subtracted from a (maybe 3D) vector. Does not make any physical sense